# Ways to reduce size of data transferred over a network?

Tags: javascript, object, byte, bandwidth

Is there any fast way to reduce the bytes of data during network transmission?

I send data from a server to the browser, and it's taking up quite a lot of bandwidth

My data looks like this, but with more properties:

```
{
  1: {width: 10.25, height: 30.75,},
  2: {width: 7.5, height: 1.25,},
}
```

*Json encoded*

Comment: when you send the objects, you send them as Objects (how) or as strings and then JSON.parse the string? I'd suggest `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse({ your object }))` which would get rid of unnecessary "white space" - for example the above would reduce from 74 to 68 characters (not much saving, is it)

Comment: You can get rid of every `width` and `height` by using an array: ` {1:[10.25,30.75],...}

Comment: *"I send the objects from a server to the browser"*: how do you currently serialize them? What is the size of the serialized string? How have you determined that is the bottleneck and not some other aspect of client-server communication or processing time on either client or server? Please provide more information.

Comment: Define "more properties" and "a lot of bandwidth". How much data are you sending from the server to the client?

Comment: You can use https://msgpack.org/ or binary serialization or you can compress the json string and send the compressed string but your server need to accept the data. Or gzip https://serverfault.com/questions/56700/is-it-possible-to-enable-http-compression-for-requests.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has a ton of solutions.
I will share some of the most common ways of network optimization.

- Strip down the data before serialization. Consider only the properties which are of importance to the communication in question.
- Consider other serialization options. JSON encoding is just one option for encoding data sent over the wire. Other options such as [binary serialization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data-serialization_formats) which is much more performant than text (in this case JSON).
- Other options you should consider include [remote procedure calls](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) which have been demonstrated to be more performant than REST.